# add extension on Log in android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I use this code to add extension for `Log` class android

```
fun Log.i2(msg:String):Unit{
    Log.i("Test",msg)
}
```

when using in the activity

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.i2("activity_main")
    }
}
```

Log.i2 not found. What's wrong?

Comment: What is your extension class extension (type: like .kt)?

Comment: type file Log.kt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve extension function in static class, you need to write extension of the companion object(refer [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects))

```
fun Log.Companion.i2(msg:String) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I need to add function on android.util.Log class in android. not new custom class

Comment: android.util.Log class is static, and to make extension function of a static class in Kotlin we need to use their companion object reference. Which if not possible in Log then I suggest to create `Any` extension function as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51259126/4878972)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, static extension methods in Kotlin is not supported without the `companion object`, because `android.util.Log` is a java class, so there is no `companion object`.

Instead, I recommend you to use a static function (package-level function, simply declared outside a class in a source code file):

```
fun logI2(msg: String) {
    Log.i("Test", msg)
}
```

And just use it like this:

```
logI2("activity_main")
```

Comment: Extending `Any` is redundant if you don't use receiver object, at this point you can create static `logI2` function.

Comment: @Pawel  why use top-level function? why don't use Any. ?

Comment: Because these two have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have created Extension function of Class `Log`.
Which is suppose to call by Instance of Class `Log`. You are trying to treat extension function as static and calling it by Class name. Which is not correct in the case